# Add web project to silverlight application - how to

Tags: silverlight, silverlight-4.0

I have created a WCF Service application, which contains a reference to a service I created.

I want to add this service application as the web component of my SL application, but I can't seem to find the option that allows me to do this.

Can someone help me out here?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you need to create a web site, then add a reference to the WCF Service from the website. You could also just have the .svc file in the website. Then right-click on your Silverlight application project and Add Service Reference. This will generate the Reference.cs (show all project files and expand the service reference to see) that will contain all the classes that you exposed in your WCF Service through return or paramaters in your methods.